# Groovy iterate Nodes with XMLHolder

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

i want to Iterate over Nodes of an XML-File with the XML-Holder.

```
def reader = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(test1 );
```

let's say the XML looks like the following:

```
<xml>
   <node>
      <val1/>
      <val2/>
   </node1>
   <node>
      <val1/>
      <val2/>
   </node2>
</xml>
```

i want to read the values from the different nodes. (val1, val2).
So i tried like that:

```
for( node in reader.getNodeValues( "//ns1:node" ))
{}
```

It really iterates over the nodes, but i don't know how the get access to the values inside them.

Thanks a lot for your help!

john

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `getNodeValues`, you probably want to call `getDomNodes` instead.  That will return you standard Java DOM nodes of class [`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).  From there you can traverse the child nodes starting with `getFirstChild` and iterating with `getNextSibling`.  Groovy's [DOMCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/dom/DOMCategory.html) adds some convenient helper methods that make it much less painful.

For example:

```
use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory) {
    for( node in reader.getDomNodes( "//ns1:node" )) {
        node.children().each { child ->
            println child
        }
    }
}
```